# Unity3D: How to instantiate a new GameObject and manipulate it

Tags: unity-game-engine, itween

I'm working on a 2D `Unity` game, and I want to create a Boom in run time and move it.

Here is part of my code.
I create a `prefab` Boom, and I drop it into inspector.

```
public GameObject Boom; // prefab Boom is drop here
void OnMouseDown()
{   
    ...
    Vector3 NewBoomPostion = new Vector3 (Luncher.transform.position.x,BoomPosition, 85);
    Instantiate(Boom, NewBoomPostion , Quaternion.identity);
    iTween.MoveTo (Boom, iTween.Hash ("y",BoomendPosition ,"speed",Boomspeed,"EaseType",BoomeaseType,"LoopType",BoomloopType));
}
```

But it throws this error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   iTween.RetrieveArgs ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is, Instantiate() instantiates a copy of object (Boom). After instantiate it, your new game object doesn't point to Boom object. It's a new game object.

```
GameObject instantiatedBoom = (GameObject) Instantiate (Boom, newBoomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
iTween.MoveTo( instantiatedBoom,....);
```

should solve it

Comment: I think you should get reference to new GO like this:
GameObject instantiatedBoom = Instantiate (bla bla) as GameObject; instead of casting it to GameObject.

Comment: Your solutions are great, and the Boom move perfectly. However, it shows another error, but it didn't affect anything. I felt wield, so I update my question.